# In Minecraft, I want to testfor if a player is on one team or the other

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to testfor if a player is on team 1, but if he is on team 2, then the comparator will still activate. I tried: `testfor @p[team=1,team=2]`
It only works for team 2 though. Probably because it is at the end. or something. Is it even possible for what I'm doing. Is there a different way maybe?

Comment: Have you tried two separate command blocks? (One testing for Team 1 and the other testing for Team 2)

Comment: I'm going to agree with @aytimothy.  The selectors use AND logic, not OR logic.

Answer (score 2):

Use two seperate commandblocks */testfor @p[team=1]* and */testfor @p[team=2]* ,then connect the comparator outputs